# Subquery is faster?

Tags: mysql

If I need to perform a complex calculation based on row data, and then alias it, in a query that might only need to operate on 10 of 10000 rows because of restrictive where clauses, is it best to use a subquery in the FROM clause, instead of using a single query?

An example is probably easier:

```
SELECT *,COMPLEX_CALC(t1.c10) AS a1 
FROM t1 
WHERE c2 > 5 AND c3 < 10 AND C6 = 4 AND c7 > 50
HAVING a1 > 100
LIMIT 1000;
```

Or

```
SELECT *,COMPLEX_CALC(ta1.c10) AS a1
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM t1
     WHERE c2 > 5 AND c3 < 10 AND C6 = 4 AND c7 > 50
     LIMIT 1000) as ta1
HAVING a1 > 100;
```

Which query would be faster? I guess the real question is - will MySQL apply the WHERE clauses before performing the COMPLEX_CALC on all rows?

Comment: Which runs faster when you try them?  Have you tried profiling the queries at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I guess the real question is - will MySQL apply the WHERE clauses
>   before performing the COMPLEX_CALC on all rows?

Yes

But if you look closely at your queries then first one runs
`COMPLEX_CALC` on all rows satisfying where clause and then taking 1000 of them

on the secon one it takes 1000 rows, run `COMPLEX_CALC` on it and take only those `having a1 > 100` which is probably less than 1000 rows

The botton line is that **your queries are not identical in output**.

in any case the `COMPLEX_CALC` is run actually twice: once for every row in having clause and then second time (upto 1000 times beacause of the limit) in `select` part.

I suggest:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT *,COMPLEX_CALC(t1.c10) AS a1 
          FROM t1 
         WHERE c2 > 5 AND c3 < 10 AND C6 = 4 AND c7 > 50) subtbl
 WHERE a1 > 100
 LIMIT 1000;
```

And its your call if you need the `limit` here or in subquery

Comment: The rows that the select sees are not determined until the WHERE clause is resolved.

Comment: Many thanks - I would not have remembered the double calculation had you not mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

From High Performance MySQL 2nd Edition:

`The most important advice we can give on subqueries is that you should usually pre- fer a join where possible, at least in current versions of MySQL. We covered this topic extensively earlier in this chapter.`

If you put 'EXPLAIN' before your query, mysql will show you what steps it will run to execute this query and with the reslt you should be able to see what's going to run faster.

Can you execute those 2 queries with 'EXPLAIN' and get back with the output?

Comment: Thanks. It was more hypothetical after a conversation at work regarding a project; so there's no real data yet.